# Which sorting algorithm does bigquery ORDER BY clause uses?

Tags: google-bigquery

Does it use bubble sort/merge sort.. type of algorithms? Is there any documentation/information available around the background execution of these type of statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why you're being downvoted, since I don't think this is described anywhere. Within a single partition, BigQuery uses [introsort](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort), with a some tricks depending on the types and number of columns in the ORDER BY clause. For example, if you have an `INT64` column named `x` and you run a query of this form:

```
SELECT x
FROM dataset.table
ORDER BY x
```

BigQuery will load all of the `x` values into a vector, then sort and return them. It's less straightforward if you have multiple columns in the select list or ORDER BY clause, though.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, Is there any additional information available around these?

Comment: Around what, specifically?

Comment: Execution algorithms for different kinds of SQL statements

Comment: @ElliottBrossard: I suspect it's getting down voted because it's quite broad and not specially related to programming/SQL. The sorting algorithm is completely abstracted away from users, with no way to control it programmatically. I agree it's interesting to know how BigQuery does its sort, but maybe it's a question more suited to stackexchange or Quora? Just my 2 cent.

Comment: Very cool information! I for one think the question is welcome, knowing the complexity of sorting algorithms is quite important for deciding how much data we'd be willing to use. I still wonder though if clustering a table on a given column would affect the sorting as well. For what I understood it seems to work sort of like an index, maybe there's optimizations to further diminish expectation of worst case scenario complexity in this case.